# php join not returning string with single element

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem which I hope you can help with

Using php I have arrays of integers I want want to return as a csv string.

ie `$arr=[1,2,3,4];`

`join(',', $arr)` returns `"1,2,3,4"` as a quoted string

but if there is only one element it returns the integer
ie `$arr==[1]`
`join(',',$arr)` returns `1` (unquoted)

How do I ensure a quoted string is always returned?

TIA

Comment: It should still be the same (string). Check [this](https://eval.in/785508)

Comment: If you really want it to return a string, you could cast it as such. $joined = (string) join(...);

Comment: That still returns an integer, but I think I have spotted the issue. The results are returned in an ajax call and it looks like this is the problem json_encode($json, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK );

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question. The code you posted above should work as requested